# Ngcontent inside multiple ngtemplates

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to create a button component(app-button) which can have multiple templates based on the parent component which uses this button component.

```
<div class="ds-u-margin-left--1 ds-u-float--left">
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="icon"></ng-container>



<ng-template #icon>
    <button class="ds-c-button">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #button>
    <button type="button" class="ds-c-button ds-c-button--success">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
</ng-template>

</div>
```

..

From my parent I am trying to initialize a component

```
<app-button>
    Save
</app-button>
```

When I have *ngTemplateOutlet="icon", it works with SAVE coming as a text on the button, but if I make it as *ngTemplateOutlet="button", the ng-content does not project itself.

It looks like ng-content works only for the first ng-template.

Can anyone please share some light on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do a ternary condition something like:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="ifSomethingTrue ? icon : button"></ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah.. same behavior

Comment: Please review your code becase something is wrong. The solution I said you works perfectly. If you change the value of the variable "somethingTrue" to true or false you will see that it works. Here you have an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8crvu

Answer (score 0):

If we use two ng-content without selector attribute, The projected element will be end up in last ng-content. Try targetted project with select attribute, which takes a CSS selector.

**Try this:**

**parent.component.ts**

```
 <child>
   <div class="icon">
    Button
   </div>
 </child>
```

**child.component.html**

```
 <div class="ds-u-margin-left--1 ds-u-float--left">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="icon"></ng-container>
    <ng-template #icon>
        <button class="ds-c-button">
            <ng-content
            select=".icon" 
            ></ng-content>
          </button>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #button>
        <button type="button" class="ds-c-button ds-c-button--success">
            <ng-content 
            select=".button"
            ></ng-content>
        </button>
    </ng-template>
    </div>
```

[For More Info](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b)

Comment: Thank you @Chellapan. This is what is happening, but I want to have the same content displayed in either of this. But i think this is a good work around

Comment: As explained in this article https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b, you can't project  use two ng-content without select attribute or @ContentChildren